# In django rest framework, put method is not working (Dropdown) api/root

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
        pro_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class ProductEnquiry(models.Model):
      productname = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      qty = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Product
       fields = ('id', 'pro_name')

 class ProductEnquirySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   productname = serializers.CharField(source='productname.pro_name')
   class Meta:
        model = ProductEnquiry
        fields = ('id','productname','qty')
   def create(self, validated_data):
        productname = validated_data.pop('productname','')
        validated_data.update({'productname_id': productname['pro_name']})
        productenquiry = ProductEnquiry.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return productenquiry
   def update(self, instance, validated_data):
       instance.productname_id = validated_data.get('productname_id', instance.productname_id)
       instance.qty = validated_data.get('qty', instance.qty)
       instance.save()
       return instance
```

Product name is Dropdown from product Model. Here post was working fine but in put method except that dropdown, quantity (qty: input field) updating successfully.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: DRF will not save the hyperlinked field changes automatically. You will have to do the save for `Product` yourself.

Comment: @arsho no error messages, it simply not updating but while i print validate data inside update() code, updated dropdown values  ( in PUT fn) are shown in my terminal

Comment: def update(self, instance, validated_data):
          instance.pro_name = validated_data.get('pro_name', instance.pro_name) instance.save()
      return instance  **This is my update code for Product @rtindru

Comment: @keerthanadevi Are you saying that the create method creates both a `Product` and `ProductEnquiry` object?

Comment: Thank you @rtindru i removed id when i assign productname to instance and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to simultaneously create and update `Product` and `ProductEnquiry` from a single uniform API interface. What you're missing is that the serializer you have written only handles the saves and updates to `ProductEnquiry`, and does not change `Product` at all.

Here's a fix to your code (untested):

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'pro_name')

class ProductEnquirySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    productname = serializers.CharField(source='productname.pro_name')

    class Meta:
        model = ProductEnquiry
        fields = ('id','productname','qty')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product_data = validated_data.pop('productname', '')
        # If you want to create a Product here; before creating a ProductEnquiry
        product_serializer = ProductSerializer(data=product_data)
        if product_serializer.is_valid():
          product = product_serializer.save()
        else:
            raise  # Raise appropriate errors

        validated_data.update({'productname_id': product.id})
        productenquiry = ProductEnquiry.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return productenquiry

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # If you want to update the Product here; before updating the ProductEnquiry
        product_data = validated_data.pop('productname', '')
        product_serializer = ProductSerializer(instance=instance.productname, data=product_data)
        if product_serializer.is_valid():
            product = product_serializer.save()
        else:
            raise  # Raise appropriate errors

        instance.productname_id = validated_data.get('productname_id', instance.productname_id)
        instance.qty = validated_data.get('qty', instance.qty)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Having said that, it might be better handled as two separate Serializer updates separated at a view level; inside a transaction block if needed.

Comment: `def update(self, instance, validated_data):
       print(validated_data)
       productname = validated_data.pop('productname')
       instance.productname_id = validated_data.get('productname_id', productname['pro_name'])
       instance.qty = validated_data.get('qty', instance.qty)
       instance.save()
       return instance.` **This one works!! Thanks for ur time and effort :)    @rtindru